# Cast error when trying to create a updatable view in H2

Tags: java, triggers, h2

I need to run insert operations inside a H2 db view. So I created a trigger based on the sample *h2/src/test/org/h2/samples/UpdatableView.java*. Unfortunately when I try to use the trigger, a error *H2Trigger cannot be cast to org.h2.api.Trigger* occurs. Below is the code used:

```
import org.h2.tools.TriggerAdapter;

public class H2Trigger extends TriggerAdapter {

private PreparedStatement prepDelete, prepInsert;

@Override
public void init(Connection conn, String schemaName, String triggerName, String tableName, boolean before, int type)
        throws SQLException {
    prepDelete = conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM H2_TABLE WHERE ID = ?");
    prepInsert = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM FINAL TABLE(INSERT INTO H2_TABLE VALUES (?, ?))");
    super.init(conn, schemaName, triggerName, tableName, before, type);
}

@Override
public void fire(Connection conn, ResultSet oldRow, ResultSet newRow) throws SQLException {
    if (oldRow != null && oldRow.next()) {
        prepDelete.setLong(1, oldRow.getLong(1));
        prepDelete.execute();
    }
    if (newRow != null && newRow.next()) {
        long id = newRow.getLong(1);
        if (newRow.wasNull()) {
            prepInsert.setNull(1, Types.BIGINT);
        } else {
            prepInsert.setLong(1, id);
        }
        prepInsert.setString(2, newRow.getString(2));
        try (ResultSet rs = prepInsert.executeQuery()) {
            rs.next();
            newRow.updateLong(1, rs.getLong(1));
            newRow.updateString(2, rs.getString(2));
            newRow.rowUpdated();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void close() throws SQLException {
    prepInsert.close();
    prepDelete.close();
}

}
```

And the trigger declaration:

```
try (Connection conn = getDatasource().getConnection(); Statement stm = conn.createStatement()) {

stm.execute("CREATE TRIGGER T_H2_VIEW INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON H2_VIEW FOR EACH ROW CALL \"" + H2Trigger.class.getName() + '"');
    stm.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO H2_VIEW ( SELECT * FROM H2_VIEW_2 )");

}
```

Do you have any idea what the problem could be? Thanks in advance!

I need to run insert operations inside a H2 db view. So I created a trigger based on the sample *h2/src/test/org/h2/samples/UpdatableView.java*. Unfortunately when I try to use the trigger, a error *H2Trigger cannot be cast to org.h2.api.Trigger* occurs.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error using your code using H2 2.1.214, which version of H2 are you on ?

Comment: @ErwanLeroux thanks for the reply. I'm using H2 2.1.210. At the moment I'm trying another solution without H2 trigger, due to project's urgency.